# How do i recall self invoking javascript function in a other function?

Tags: javascript, html, function, html-lists, addeventlistener

I had to recall the  self invoked method, to add event listener to the newly added elements to the list

```js
var textPop = document.getElementById('textPopper');
var elements = document.getElementById('our-list');

var reloader = (function reload() {
    document.querySelectorAll('ul li').forEach(function(click) {
        click.addEventListener("click", function() {
            textPop.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
        })
    });

}
)();


function addItem() {
    elements.innerHTML += "<li> Something new stuff </li>";
    reloader();  //getting error here (Uncaught TypeError: again is not a function)
    }
```

```html
            <h3 id="textPopper">Text popper </h3>
            <ul id="our-list">
                <li>First item </li>
                <li>Second item</li>
                <li>Third item</li>
                <li>Fourth item</li>
            </ul>
            <script src="my.js"></script>
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting? It is good to add all the details in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reloader` is not the self-invoking function. It is the **result** of the self-invoking function. If, inside the self-invoking function, you put `return 2`, reloader would be 2.

You don't want it to be a self-invoking function. Just have reloader be the function itself, and then call `reloader()` after assignment.

Comment: can we recall an self invoking function, which doesn't return anything , but  to be called in another function?

Comment: No, there's really no reason though to avoid just assigning the function to a variable and calling it like normal. Don't worry about it being self-invoking, that isn't doing you any special favors.

Answer (score 1):

The IIFE executes and assigns the result to `reloader`, hence you can't call `reloader()`

From what I understand looking at your code you might need to assign the function itself to `reloader`, execute it and then call it again as needed.

```
var reloader = function() {
  document.querySelectorAll('ul li').forEach(function(click) {
    click.addEventListener("click", function() {
      textPop.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
    })
  });
};

reloader();


function addItem() {
  elements.innerHTML += "<li> Something new stuff </li>";
  reloader(); //getting error here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So just define it as a function and than call it. The problem you have is the varaible reloader holds what ever the function returns. Since the function does not return anything, than it is undefined.

```js
var textPop = document.getElementById('textPopper');
var elements = document.getElementById('our-list');

var reloader = function() {
  document.querySelectorAll('ul li').forEach(function(click) {
    click.addEventListener("click", function() {
      textPop.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
    })
  });
};

reloader()


function addItem() {
  elements.innerHTML += "<li> Something new stuff </li>";
  reloader();
}

window.setTimeout(addItem, 1000);
```

```html
<h3 id="textPopper">Text popper </h3>
<ul id="our-list">
  <li>First item </li>
  <li>Second item</li>
  <li>Third item</li>
  <li>Fourth item</li>
</ul>
<script src="my.js"></script>
```

Other option is to use event delegation and not even need to rebind events.

```js
var textPop = document.getElementById('textPopper');
var ul = document.getElementById('our-list');

//bind click event to the parent
ul.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  //e.target will give you the li that was clicked on
  textPop.innerHTML = e.target.innerHTML;
})

function addItem() {
  var li = document.createElement("li")
  li.innerHTML = "Something new stuff"
  ul.appendChild(li);
}

window.setTimeout(addItem, 1000);
```

```html
<h3 id="textPopper">Text popper </h3>
<ul id="our-list">
  <li>First item </li>
  <li>Second item</li>
  <li>Third item</li>
  <li>Fourth item</li>
</ul>
<script src="my.js"></script>
```